# How to export email in Tutanota?

Tags: email, export, tutanota

[According to Tutanota's Reddit account](https://www.reddit.com/r/tutanota/comments/48rsp8/can_i_download_my_emails/d0w4zyy/), exporting individual email messages is possible.

Comment: Can you create Tutanota tag?

Answer (score 1):

[If you click on 'Move' you can move the selected mail to any of the given folders or you can export it as .eml-file.](https://tutanota.com/howto)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://tutanota.com/faq#generalMail,

> - You can drag and drop all selected emails to your local file system by pressing ctrl or alt while dragging. In the desktop clients, you can decide whether to export emails as msg or eml files under 'Settings' -> 'Desktop' -> 'Email export file format'.
> - You can click the symbols displayed to the right: 'Cancel', 'Move', 'Delete', or the three dots. When you click the three dots, you can choose one of the following options: 'Mark unread', 'Mark read' or 'Export'.

[image: Export individual email]